# Default DNS records with WHMCS + cPanel/WHM + NetEarthOne

Tags: domains, dns, cpanel, whmcs, whm

I use the billing system WHMCS to automatically send invoices and use it's auto-setup functions. My control panel is cPanel/WHM. I use NetEarthOne to resell domains. cPanel/WHM and NetEarthOne are both fully compatible with WHMCS.

I asked my host:

> If a user buys a hosting package and a domain name, what are the standard DNS records? Does the client have to set them up manually?

They didn't understand that, so I asked:

> If a user buys hosting package + domain name, do they have to setup the domain name to point to the hosting package manually?

They said:

> If you use some billing system like WHMCS, the account for this order should be created automatically as well as DNS zone for this domain.
>   No need to make any additional changes.

I replied:

> Interesting to know. Yes, I'm using WHMCS. I don't need to setup something in LogicBoxes or something?

(LogicBoxes is the control panel for NetEarthOne and several other registrars such as ResellerClub)

They said:

> No, you do not need to do this.

Could someone please confirm this?

Comment: If you are struggling to communicate with them why are you wasting your time on them?

Comment: create a test account, see what happens

Comment: @bybe ? I'm happy with their support.

Comment: @Steve I actually should, but I can't test a domain for free.

Comment: I use WHMCS and I can create an account on the server with a domain name that hasn't been registered.  Obviously it won't work as expected, cpanel/whm will set it up with DNS as though it is real.

Comment: @Steve I don't understand your comment. Rephrase please.

Comment: Create an order with a fake domain name.  Get WHMCS to create the account on the server but don't let it register the domain.  On the server it will be set up just like a registered domain so you will be able to see the DNS settings.

Comment: @Steve Or just create an account via cPanel directly ;)

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards but that doesn't solve his OP of whether WHMCS is setting up DNS properly

Comment: @Steve I am the OP...

Comment: DOH!  :o)  Well to rephrase then,  your question was about DNS setup when created by WHMCS, so why would you test it in cpanel directly?

Comment: @Steve I didn't understand your comments earlier, but by coming here by coincidence and rereading your comments I understand them now. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, sometimes it takes a while for that "aha" moment! :o)

Answer (score 1):

As long as your installation of WHMCS is configured to with both the server (cPanel/WHM) and your domain name registrar, I can confirm that you do not need to create any DNS records - WHMCS will create this automatically upon domain name registration.